# Pathogen ignoring ftplugin scripts

Tags: vim, pathogen, ftplugin

I'm trying to use `Pathogen` to manage Vim plugins. I had a couple of scripts I made in `.vim/ftplugins`.

I installed Pathogen but now none of the scripts in ftplugins runs.

I tried adding a directory inside `.vim/bundle` with the scripts but it didn't work (it was `.vim/bundle/local/ftplugin/python.vim`)

Any idea how can I make Pathogen load the scripts in ftplugin directory?

First lines of my [`.vimrc`](http://pastebin.com/JmP2V9rR):

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
"execute pathogen#infect()
```

Only works with that line commented out.

I am running `gvim` from a Bash prompt with the filename as first parameter like this:

```
$ gvim some/path/somefile.py
```

I expect to see the file with my predefined colorscheme for Python files defined in ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim and all the other settings defined in that script.

The ~/.vim/bundle directory is empty.

Pathogen is in  ~/.vim/autoload and there is nothing more there.

```
$ ls ~/.vim/ftplugin/
css.vim  html.vim  javascript.vim  python_pep8.vim  python_pyflakes.vim  python.vim  rst.vim  xml.vim

$ ls ~/.vim
autoload  bundle  colors  doc  ftdetect  ftplugin  plugins  ScrollColor.vim  spell  syntax
```

Comment: I would first make sure that you do have Pathogen installed. Second, if they're plugins of your own, I suggest you put them in the normal folder, instead of the `/bundle` folder. Just because it's easier to reach them that way. So put that under `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Comment: @Eduan Pathogen is installed and my scripts are in the normal folders. When I enable Pathogen in .vimrc the scripts stop loading.

Comment: So, your plugins are under `~/.vim/bundle/local/ftplugin/` correct? Could you try moving them to `/.vim/ftplugin/`. I'm not aware of Pathogen deactivating these plugins if you put them there.

Comment: @Eduan I tried both locations, even at the same time, none of them worked

Comment: @Eduan Pathogen AFAIK just adds items to `&rtp`, it does not remove them from there. But if pathogen is installed and run correctly it makes no sense in moving back and forth: this should produce identical results (except for a few edge cases), meaning that pathogen is not actually used correctly. @F.C. It is almost impossible to tell what you have done wrong without seeing your `.vimrc` (better: diff, before and after you installed pathogen).

Comment: Wondering whether it works if you put `:filetype` and `:syntax` calls after `:execute`? Official README suggest doing just this in the second section: first `:execute`, second `:syntax`, third `:filetype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with filetype detection, this is the [Pathogen issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/38).

The work around in my case was simple, use this to enable Pathogen:

```
set nocompatible
"execute pathogen#infect()    " breaks filetype detection
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

What I did to find out was to remove my ~/.vim directory and start with a clean one. Adding things one by one and checking the results. I realized it was not detecting the correct filetype (when I opened an empty file detection was ok, but it was not when opening an existing file).

Answer (score 1):

Putting my comment here:

Wondering whether it works if you put `:filetype` and `:syntax` calls after `:execute`? Official `README` suggest doing just this in the second section: first `:execute`, second `:syntax`, third `:filetype`. Note: DO NOT *disable* filetype prior to `:execute` like @Eduan suggested, just don’t enable it until `:execute` is called:

```
set nocompatible
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

---

And, by the way, [never use `*map`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Comment: no luck, the scripts in `ftplugins` still don't work, they work as soon as I comment out the line `execute pathogen#infect()`

Comment: @F.C. Wondering then how do you test (exact steps). And what does `bundle/` directory contains.

Comment: added the information you ask to the question, I just open a file from a Bash prompt and see if the settings are there (key bindings, colors, etc.)

Comment: @F.C. This is not “exact steps”. In order for filetype settings to work you need to open some file, but I see no information about what you open. Ah, and what does `~/.vim` contains? Pathogen itself is installed into `~/.vim/autoload`?

Comment: thanks for your comments, I added more information in the question

Comment: @F.C. I currently have no idea what it *can* be. Can you provide `:scriptnames` output with and without `:execute` line commented when opening `*.py` file, same for `:echo &runtimepath` (to do this you can just paste from clipboard after using `:redi@+|scrip|ec&rtp|redi END`). Though it is unlikely that it will give the clue right away, so using `set verbosefile=/tmp/verbose.log verbose=15` on the line just before `:execute` call and `set verbose=0` on the line just after and posting the `/tmp/verbose.log` file (after you exit vim) will also be good.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see your problem, putting this in an answer instead of a comment for the sake of the example code's clarity.

Try this:

```
" Set the filetype stuff to off, required for Pathogen
filetype off
filetype plugin indent off

execute pathogen#infect()

" You can now turn it on again
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Instead of your current setup.

Comment: @F.C. Hmm... Have no idea what it could be then. :(

Comment: See the source code of `pathogen#infect`: it does setting filetype off and then on on its own.

Comment: Ah I see, I use Vundle, thought it would be the same procedure (since Vundle does say it's the same except the extras).

Comment: I removed all the lines `filetype` but the scripts in `ftplugins` are not used