# vim, pathogen, and load order of ftplugin files

Tags: vim, python-mode, pathogen

I've been using Vim and [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for a while, and things were working fine, but recently I've started having load order issues with my ftplugin configuration.

The specific problem I'm having right now is that [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) is overriding my ftplugin settings. I've got a `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` that contains the following line:

```
setlocal textwidth=119
```

python-mode comes with its own ftplugin file, which also sets `textwidth`, in [`~/.vim/bundle/python-mode/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim`](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim#L28).

**The problem is that Vim is now loading python-mode's ftplugin file *after* my ftplugin file, so I'm ending up with its `textwidth=79`.** I recently had to reinstall MacPorts, and I think something must have changed in the stock configuration.

I've tried various tricks involving turning filetype/plugin detection off before invoking pathogen, per [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383502/pathogen-does-not-load-plugins) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264372/pathogen-ignoring-ftplugin-scripts) answers, but none of them are helping.

Through the use of `verbose set textwidth?` and some `echomsg` debugging, I know that both ftplugin files are being invoked, and that they're being invoked in the wrong (for my needs) order.

**Is there any way to force Vim/pathogen to invoke my ftplugin files after those of the plugins?**

I've even tried putting my settings into `~/.vim/after/plugin/pymode.vim`, but that's loaded immediately after pathogen sets up the plugin, so it still runs before `ftplugin` files, which only get loaded once I edit a Python file.

Comment: I'm solving this specific issue by setting `let g:pymode_options = 0` in `~/.vim/after/plugin/pymode.vim`, since I don't want any of python-mode's options, but I'm still looking for a more general answer to this load-order issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that maybe this never worked the way I thought. I didn't realize that Vim also supported `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`, so I was able to move my overrides to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` and get the behavior I was expecting. I'm loath to answer my own questions on SO, but hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: I think answering one's own questions is specifically encouraged. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 6):

Plain Vim loads the plugin scripts in **alphabetical** order. This is from `:help load-plugins`

```
... all directories in the 'runtimepath' option will be
searched for the "plugin" sub-directory and all files ending in ".vim"
will be sourced (in alphabetical order per directory), also in
subdirectories.
```

So you can set plugin loading order by renaming `<filetype>_plugin.vim` to `<filetype>/35plugin.vim`. 35 is your desired loading order. I think this should work with Pathogen too by renaming the plugin directories inside `bundle`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: It works with Pathogen by renaming the plugin directories inside `bundle` --- tested in v7.4.  (Yeah, I need to update. :D )  Separately, note that `autoload` files may be loaded in a different order than their directory names, depending on when functions in those files are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm still looking for a more general answer to this load-order issue

As far as I know, you can't really do it with Pathogen. It is really easy with NeoBundle. Pathogen is really minimal, it doesn't provide you with a lot of flexibility - it does only one thing and does it well. If you're looking for configurability, I think you're using the wrong tool.

EDIT: Not really sure about ftplugins, but bundles in general are loaded as you specify them (with Vundle/NeoBundle). So I realise that this maybe is not the most relevant of answers.